# What is # as prefix?

Tags: haskell

If we go [here](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/validation.html) there are some calls to validation like `validateField #title nonEmpty`. So what is `#` here? There is a postfix `#` which is used along with `-XMagicHash` extension but I can't find any info on prefix notation

Comment: This is an overloaded label (bottom of https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.16.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Exp)

Comment: See https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_labels.html

Comment: Thanks! Could you please make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Also note that text between the quotes `[hsx|` and `|]` is *not* Haskell code, like the text between double quotes `"`. That text is parsed according to the definition of `hsx`, which requires its own syntax -- apparently it uses `#title` to refer to some named entity `title`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this may look like coming from `-XMagicHash`, this is actually an overloaded label. You can learn more about them in the [GHC User Guide](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_labels.html)